# How to increase timeout of hover doc in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ,  I have the hover doc showing when I hover my mouse, great.  But after ~3 seconds, it goes away.  How can I make that hover doc window stay open? I looked through Settings and couldn't see where to change that.  (I DO see how to set tooltip delay, but not the how long to show it)

Comment: I can't confirm the described behavior in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4 on Windows 10. The documentation popup never goes away for me (until I move the cursor away from the code element the documentation was displayed for).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Hmm.. once I updated to that version, it's working as expected, thanks.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Worked yesterday, but now today it's back to disappearing after 3 secs.  Lame.

Comment: Please report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...).

Answer (score 0):

I guess upgrading to 2019.3.4 fixed this.  Thanks @CrazyCoder

EDIT: Nope.. it's back again today. Hover to see the doc, then take my hands completely off mouse and it still disappears after ~3 sec.